# Finding overlap of sessions

Tags: python, session, tree, intervals

I have an arbitrary number of sessions with start and end timestamps

Some of these sessions overlap.  Multiple sessions could overlap at the same time.

I am trying to find an algorithm that can detect the number of seconds of overlap.  IE given 3 sessions like

```
-ID-|-start-|-end-|
--1-|-----4-|--10-|
--2-|-----5-|--12-|
--3-|-----8-|--13-|
```

have it return a number that is the number of seconds that the sessions overlap.

I have read about [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) and looked at python packages like [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=interval%20tree%20python&oq=interval%20tree%20python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4061j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

However, I am unsure how to get the number of seconds of overlap for a given set of records.  Do you know of an algorithm or package?  Python preferred but open to other languages and I can reimplement.

Answer (score 1):

The first idea which came to my mind with a complexity of O(n log n) for sorting. If `starts` and `ends` are sorted already, the algorithm has complexity of O(n).

```
int findOverlappingTimes(int[] starts, int ends[]) {

    // TODO: Sort starts array
    // TODO: Sort ends array
    // TODO: Assert starts.length == ends.length

    int currStartsIndex = 0;
    int currEndsIndex = 0;

    int currOverlaps = 0;
    int lastOverlapIndex = -1;

    int result = 0;

    while (currEndsIndex < ends.length) {

        if (currStartsIndex < starts.length && starts[currStartsIndex] < ends[currEndsIndex]) {
            if (++currOverlaps == 2) { // Start counting if at least two intervals overlap
                lastOverlapIndex = currStartsIndex;
            }
            currStartsIndex++;
        } else {
            if (--currOverlaps <= 1 && lastOverlapIndex != -1) { // Stop counting
                result += ends[currEndsIndex] - starts[lastOverlapIndex];
                lastOverlapIndex = -1;
            }
            currEndsIndex++;
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

The output for your input set

```
findOverlappingTimes(new int[] { 4, 5, 8 }, new int[] { 10, 12, 13 })
```

returns `7`.

The basic idea behind the algorithm is to iterate over the sessions and count the number of currently overlapping sessions. We start counting the overlapping time if at least two sessions overlap at the current time and stop counting the overlapping time if the overlaps end.

Here are some more test cases and their respective output:

```
findOverlappingTimes(new int[] { 0 }, new int[] { 0 }) = 0
findOverlappingTimes(new int[] { 10 }, new int[] { 10 }) = 0
findOverlappingTimes(new int[] { 10 }, new int[] { 20 }) = 0
findOverlappingTimes(new int[] { 10, 10 }, new int[] { 10, 10 }) = 0
findOverlappingTimes(new int[] { 10, 10 }, new int[] { 11, 11 }) = 1
findOverlappingTimes(new int[] { 10, 10, 10 }, new int[] { 11, 11, 12 }) = 1
findOverlappingTimes(new int[] { 10, 10, 10, 50, 90, 110 }, new int[] { 11, 12, 12, 100, 150, 160 }) = 52
findOverlappingTimes(new int[] { 4, 5, 8, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300 }, new int[] { 10, 12, 13, 110, 200, 200, 320, 330 }) = 27
```

Comment: Thank you for writing this.  It works if all ending timestamps are in order but they might not be.  For example findOverlappingTimes([10, 13],[18, 15]) outputs 5, but the actual overlap is 2.  Trying to think how to make this work for that case too

Comment: Yes, this is also stated in the answer. If it is not a possibility to sort the `ends` array as well, I can think of another solution which can handle unsorted input data as well.